# How to fix "name is not defined" when it is defined?

Tags: python

I got an error "NameError: name 'first_name' is not defined".

```py
narek = {
    "first_name": "Narek",
    "last_name": "Kuloyan",
    "age": 27,
    "city": "Yerevan",
    }
…
people = [narek, tigran, karen]
for mard in people:
    for tvyal, info in mard.items():
        anun = info[first_name] + info[last_name]
        print("Anun azganun: "+ anun.title())
        print("\nTariq: " + str(info[age]))
```

Comment: A key in a dictionary is not a variable, so there is no variable with that name.

Comment: No, it isn't defined. It's a key in a dictionary. That does not actually create a name in the global namespace. `narek['first_name']` would work.

Comment: Actually, no, my suggestion wouldn't work. I don't understand what this code is supposed to do. This code errors way before that.

Comment: Thank you for answers, but I want for every line, not just for Narek. Can you offer a solution?

Comment: if will print first name+ last name on the same lane, then age on new and move to other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you were expecting to achieve, this code should do the work.

```
narek = {
    "first_name": "Narek",
    "last_name": "Kuloyan",
    "age": 27,
    "city": "Yerevan",
    }

people = [narek]

for mard in people:
    anun = mard['first_name'] + mard['last_name']
    print("Anun azganun: "+ anun.title())
    print("\nTariq: " + str(mard['age']))
```

Comment: You clearly didn't run this because you originally carried over some invalid characters. And removing them still won't make it run. Test your solutions before you post them!

Comment: @roganjosh it won't work if tigran and karen are not defined, but I suppose they are defined in the author's code

Comment: А почему -1 показывает у ответа?

Comment: @DavidAvetisyan кто-то решил минусануть:)